# Linking data fields with discriminated unions causing errors

Tags: typescript, typescript2.2

I'm working on an Ionic (3.0.0) app, and frequently want to link the types of two fields in a data `interface`. For example, a `NotificationData` has `verb: 'mention' | 'share' | ...` and `reference: ProfileReference | DocumentReference | ...` fields, but really, a `NotificationData` is a union type:

```ts
{ verb: 'mention', reference: ProfileReference } | { verb: 'share', reference: DocumentReference }
```

So far, so good. There are other fields that don't change with `verb`, so I usually create a base interface, extend it in different ways, and then take the union, like so:

```ts
type X = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
type Y = 'd' | 'e' | 'f';

interface I { x: X, other: Y };
interface A extends I { x: 'a', other: 'd' };
interface B extends I { x: 'b', other: 'e' };
interface C extends I { x: 'c', other: 'f' };
type J = A | B | C;
```

This is fine as long as I'm hard-coding the data

```ts
const j: J = { x: 'a', other: 'd' } // OK
```

or generating an entire  from a `switch`

```ts
function f(x: X): J {
  switch (x) {
    case 'a': return { x, other: 'd' };
    case 'b': return { x, other: 'e' };
    case 'c': return { x, other: 'f' };
    default: ((y: never) => {})(x);
  }
}
// OK
```

But if I try to generate it another way, Typescript is complains:

```ts
function other(x: X): Y {
  switch (x) {
    case 'a': return 'd';
    case 'b': return 'e';
    case 'c': return 'f';
    default: ((y: never) => {})(x);
  }
}

function g(x: X): J {
  return { x, other: other(x) }
}
// Error:
// Type '{ x: X; other: number; }' is not assignable to type Z.
//   Type '{ x: X; other: number; }' is not assignable to type 'C'.
//     Types of property 'x' are incompatible.
//       Type 'X' is not assignable to type '"c"'.
//         Type '"a"' is not assignable to type '"c"'.
```

In fact, these errors come up even if there's no linking of data fields:

```ts
interface I2 { x: X, other: any };
interface A2 extends I2 { x: 'a' };
interface B2 extends I2 { x: 'b' };
interface C2 extends I2 { x: 'c' };
type J2 = A2 | B2 | C2;

function h(x: X): J2 { return { x, other: 0 }; }
// Error:
// Type '{ x: X; other: number; }' is not assignable to type J2.
//   Type '{ x: X; other: number; }' is not assignable to type 'C2'.
//     Types of property 'x' are incompatible.
//       Type 'X' is not assignable to type '"c"'.
//         Type '"a"' is not assignable to type '"c"'.
```

I could just use `I` in my type signatures

```ts
const xs: X[] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const is: I2[] = xs.map(x => ({ x, other: 0 })) // OK
```

but this loses the linking of fields that I wanted in the first place. I could also just always use a `switch` as in `function f` above, e.g.

```ts
const js: J[] = xs.map(f); // OK
```

but I'd like to be able to do this without creating a separate function, like

```ts
const j2s: J2[] = xs.map(x => ({ x, other: 0 }))
// Error: ... Type '"a"' is not assignable to type '"c"'.
```

and anyway, this feels like something that Typescript should be able to express/handle.

So my question is, **is there a better way to express this linked-field type information in Typescript?** Or another way to procedurally generate a `J[]` from an `X[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of TypeScript's type system. I'll simplify the code in your question to make the problem easier to spot:

```
function f(x: 'a' | 'b' | 'c'): { x: 'a' } | { x: 'b' } | { x: 'c' } {
    return { x: x };
}

// Type '{ x: "a" | "b" | "c"; }' is not assignable to type '{ x: "a"; } | { x: "b"; } | { x: "c"; }'.
```

This error message is a little easier to understand. The type checker sees you using a value of type `'a' | 'b' | 'c'` as the `x` entry in the object, and infers a type of `{ x: 'a' | 'b' | 'c' }` for the expression. This is not the same type as `{ x: 'a' } | { x: 'b' } | { x: 'c' }`! In particular, the type checker doesn't understand that every possible value of type `'a' | 'b' | 'c'` does in fact produce a valid object of type `{ x: 'a' } | { x: 'b' } | { x: 'c' }`.

So the compiler needs some help. We can get our ducks in a row by performing a case analysis before constructing the object:

```
function f(x: 'a' | 'b' | 'c'): { x: 'a' } | { x: 'b' } | { x: 'c' } {
    switch (x)
    {
        case 'a': return { x: x };
        case 'b': return { x: x };
        case 'c': return { x: x };
    }
}
```

In each branch of the `case`, `x`'s type gets narrowed (to `'a'`, `'b'`, or `'c'`, respectively), so the returned expressions are of type `{ x: 'a' }`, `{ x: 'b' }` and `{ x: 'c' }`, respectively. These clearly do type check at `{ x: 'a' } | { x: 'b' } | { x: 'c' }`.

If you really can't afford the extra keystrokes required for the `switch` statement, I think the simplest and most practical workaround is just to turn the type system off temporarily.

```
function f(x: 'a' | 'b' | 'c'): { x: 'a' } | { x: 'b' } | { x: 'c' } {
    return <any>{ x: x };
}
```

---

You might reasonably object that TypeScript *should* be able to tell that `{ x: 'a' | 'b' | 'c' }` is assignable to `{ x: 'a' } | { x: 'b' } | { x: 'c' }`. Think about this like a compiler writer: what would an algorithm to check types like that look like?

1. Break up the union type `'a' | 'b' | 'c'` into its constituent literal types.
2. Break up the result type `{ x: 'a' } | { x: 'b' } | { x: 'c' }` into its constituent object types.
3. For each pair of types (`{x: x}`, `resultType`), compare the types to see if they're assignable.

In pseudocode:

```
foreach (t: Type in 'a' | 'b' | 'c')
{
    var checks = false;
    foreach (u: Type in { x: 'a' } | { x: 'b' } | { x: 'c' })
    {
        if ({ x: t } :<= u)
        {
            checks = true;
        }
    }
    if (!checks)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

We've written an O(n^2) type checking algorithm! An alternative approach might be to put the types into a sum-of-products normal form - this would allow you to compare, say, `{ x: { y: 'a' | 'b' } | { y: 'c' | 'd' } }` with `{ x: { y: 'a' } } | { x: { y: 'b' } } | { x: { y: 'c' } } | { x: { y: 'd' } }` - but [the normalisation algorithm blows up exponentially](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form#Conversion_into_CNF), and you still wouldn't be able to handle recursive type synonyms.

The moral of the story is, in practice type systems aren't *just* set theory. Just because two types contain the same set of values doesn't mean you should expect them to be judged equal by a machine. In the most advanced type systems - *dependent* type systems - it's common for the type checker to require a computational *proof* of your program's soundness. (For example, you may know the length of your array to be `n + m`, but if the type checker was expecting an array of length `m + n`, you have to write extra code to convince the machine that you've fulfilled your obligations.)

Comment: Thanks! While this doesn't help me solve my problem, it does help me understand the underlying issues. Since posting, I've used a combination of switch/if case-narrowing and `as Foo` to balance the type system with code readability.